# How to set state with spread operators, when using variables for keys?

Tags: reactjs, variables, setstate

I have a certain piece of state like:

```
    this.state = {
     receipts: {
       qwer12r: {color: 'red', size: '20'}
       qas123e: {color: 'green', size: '21'}
    }
   };
```

these values are collected from two different forms. hence the keys correspond to different form IDs. The forms have drop-downs from where I successfully return the formID and the selected value.

But, using the formID, I want to burrow into the formID object and update only one of the properties.

The components are structured such that the children are the forms, and the parent is a form creator / duplicator.

This implies that the change functions need to be passed down to the children to retrieve their formID, and correspondingly update the correct state, belonging to the correct form.

I have tried the spread operator in many different ways, all having failed to produce the expected result.

In the parent
Here's what I've already tried:

```
handleChange(formNumber, value) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      receipts: {
        ...prevState.receipts,
        [formNumber]: {
          ...prevState.formNumber,
          color: value
        }
      }
    }));
```

and this:

```
handleChange(formNumber, value) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      receipts: {
        ...prevState.receipts,
        [formNumber]: {
          ...`prevState.receipts.${formNumber}`,
          color: value
        }
      }
    }));
```

and this:

```
handleChange(formNumber, value) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      receipts: {
        ...prevState.receipts,
        [formNumber]: {
          ...`prevState.${formNumber}`,
          color: value
        }
      }
    }));
```

In the Child:
Here is handler attached to the onChange of the color dropdown in the form:

```
onChange={value =>this.handleValueChange(this.props.formNumber, value)}
```

and here is that method definition:

```
handleValueChange= (formId, value) => {
    this.props.handleformColorChange(formId, value);
  };
```

If the child form calls the handleChange method like handleChange('qwer12r', 'blue'),

the expected result:

```
this.state = {
receipts: {
   qwer12r: {color: 'blue', size: '20'}
   qas123e: {color: 'green', size: '21'}
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Access receipts with bracket notation

```
handleChange(formNumber, value) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        receipts: {
            ...prevState.receipts,
            [formNumber]: {
                ...prevState.receipts[formNumber],
                color: value
            }
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful.

```
handleChange(formId, value) = () => {
   this.setState({
       [formId] : {
          ...this.state[formId],
          color: value
       }
   )}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the property by bracket notation, Below is the simple implementation for same.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { receipts: { firstForm: { color: "" } } }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(formNumber, value) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
         receipts: {
          ...prevState.receipts,
          [formNumber]: {
            ...prevState[formNumber],
            color: value
          }
       }
    }));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <Child formNumber="firstForm"
        handleformColorChange={this.handleChange}
        value={this.state.receipts.firstForm.color}></Child>
    )
  }
}
```